Finding the number of ways to rearrange N unique objects such that every single object has new object as its neighbor each time in new arrangement.
Lets say we have 4 object A,B,C,D. We want number of arrangements such that no object gets the old neighbor it had in all past arrangements.
If we start with A B C D then we want new arrangements such that B shouldn't be the neighbor of A and vice versa, C shouldn't be the neighbor of B and vice versa, D shouldn't be the neighbor of C and vice versa. So then the new arrangement will be C A D B. Now we want new arrangement such that A shouldn't have C as well as  B as its neighbor. As we had B as A's neighbor in first arrangement and C in 2nd arrangement. We should consider all the past neighbors for each object. Similarly B shouldn't have A,C,D as its neighbor, C shouldn't have B,A,D as its neighbor and D shouldn't have C,A,B as its neighbor.
And there exists no such arrangement. So for N=4 we have total 2 arrangements.
So it doesn't matter from which arrangement you start. We want for given N how many such arrangements are possible.

It is similar to finding the maximum number of Hamiltonian paths can be removed before no more such paths can be found in a complete graph$\ K_n $. The key points are:

Total Number of Edges: A complete graph$\ K_n $ has$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges.

Edges in Each Hamiltonian Path: Each Hamiltonian path uses$\ n-1 $ edges.

Maximum Number of Hamiltonian Paths:

The maximum number of distinct Hamiltonian paths that can be removed from$\ K_n $ is given by the formula:
$
 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor
 $
This is because each Hamiltonian path uses$\ n-1 $ edges, and to ensure no edges are reused, the number of Hamiltonian paths can be removed is at most$\ \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor $.



Examples:

For$\ n = 7 $:
Total edges:$\ \frac{7(7-1)}{2} = 21 $
Maximum number of Hamiltonian paths can be removed:$\ \left\lfloor \frac{7}{2} \right\rfloor = 3 $, So $Ans. = 3$


First Path:$\ a \to b \to c \to d \to e \to f \to g $
Second Path:$\ a \to c \to e \to g \to b \to d \to f $
Third Path:$\ a \to d \to g \to c \to f \to b \to e $


@ aaryan tussi great ho ji

Let the objects be $V=\{1,...,n\}$. At the start, we don't have any restrictions so, represented as a graph, we start with the complete graph $G:=K_n$.
Now in each iteration, we choose a hamilton path on the graph, and then remove all edges in the path from the graph.
The question then becomes: What is the longest sequence of iterations possible?
If we instead choose Hamilton Cycles on the graph (i.e. if the objects are seated around a circular table), then the question of  whether the longest sequence of iterations exhausts all edges is equivalent to whether or not the graph has a Hamilton decomposition.
Using the Walecki construction, one can show that we can decompose $K_n$ into Hamilton Cycles if and only if $n$ is odd, and into Hamilton Paths if and only if $n$ is even. For a paper discussing the Walecki construction see e.g. The Wonderful Walecki Construction.
So for $n$ even, the answer is $n/2$.
For $n$ odd, there exists a decomposition into $n/2$ Hamiltonian Cycles, which is also the longest sequence of iterations, since the iteration only stops when $n/2<n$ edges are left.

Thanks @Sudix. This is really helpful!

Don't we have general formula for it?

@shubhamkakade Please have a look at the links, and if that doesn't help, specify what exactly you want this formula to do
